# BGE: How to make an object leave [skid]marks on another object

Tags: animation, game-engine, workflow

I want to know how to make an object leave marks on another in the game engine, like skidmarks as in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeVpS79tYmY). I'm not looking for a tutorial, just the logic of it.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this (and I tested) would be to have your trigger object (tires) rigged with an **Edit object** actuator set to *add object* **:** Activate upon a collision with ground or a sharp turn (Make sure True level triggering is on).

Set the *time* to 30, and the target object to be a plane textured like a portion or you tires tread. Alpha channel turn down.

I got good effects with a rolling monkey head, so *hey*; why not a car?

Comment: I want to try that, it sound really neat (the only PB I can see is the potentially uncontrollable polycount increase) so ; I already got an always pulse sensor on my car object, I connected it via a AND to a Edit actuator set to add a small plane I made, but nothing happens ; What steps am I missing?

Comment: OK So the "mark" object [has to be on another, hidden layer](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Logic/Actuators/Edit_Object). Now it works, only my 30 objects won't stay there, they follow the car :)

Comment: ...Aaaand just set "time" to 0 to leave the marks on the track. Now I just have to replace my AND w/ a python module that (pretends to) manage friction (sharp turns, braking & accels) Vince, this is excellent, thank you very much!

Comment: Problem is it kills the performance... Damned, how can I just scratch the texture's surface?

Comment: Well, they don't need to stay there forever, you can make them disappear after some time. also at only four vertices a-piece it shouldn't be a problem. Maybe slow down the true level triggering delay value?

Comment: I did this, and it worked very well B TW, leaving less marks, nice ; No, my PB is the sensor : Somehow I can't get my rigid body to just stay put on the track plane, only hovering slightly, and a (property-based) collision sensor, when "on the track" oscillates True/False, and THIS is what makes is slow. The actuator is doing a good job, Your method actually works.

Comment: Are you wanting your vehicle to be able to tip and die? otherwise it just needs to be Dynamic phisics type